# Cannot get openjpa tools to run from the command line

Tags: openjpa

What I did:

- download and extract the latest openjpa release (3.0.0)
- download the mariadb jdbc driver jar and copy it to the same directory where openjpa-all-3.0.0.jar is located
- inside the same directory, create a subdirectory META_INF and a file META-INF/persistence.xml with the following contents:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <persistence version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="openjpa">
      <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
      <properties>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/databasename"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="dbuser"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="dbpassword"/>
          <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false"/>
          <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
          <property name="openjpa.Log" value="SQL=TRACE"/>
          <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrettyPrint=true, PrettyPrintLineLength=120, PrintParameters=true, MaxActive=10, MaxIdle=5, MinIdle=2, MaxWait=60000"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  ```
- create an empty directory src as a sub-directory of where the openjpa and mariadb driver jars are
- ran the following command:

  java -cp ./:openjpa-all-3.0.0.jar:mariadb-java-client-2.4.0.jar:openjpa-all-3.0.0.jar org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool -pkg some.package -d ./src

Instead of getting any kind of output, or an error related to generation, I get:

```
8  INFO   [main] openjpa.Tool - The reverse mapping tool will run on the database.  The tool is gathering schema information; this process may take some time.  Enable the org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.Schema logging category to see messages about schema data.
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-3.0.0-r422266:1833209 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@f248234b". 
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:71)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:850)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:733)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDataSource(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:879)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDataSource2(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:921)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.SchemaGenerator.<init>(SchemaGenerator.java:86)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool.run(ReverseMappingTool.java:2027)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool.run(ReverseMappingTool.java:2005)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool.run(ReverseMappingTool.java:1882)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool$1.run(ReverseMappingTool.java:1863)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.launchRunnable(Configurations.java:762)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.runAgainstAllAnchors(Configurations.java:747)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool.main(ReverseMappingTool.java:1858)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried variations of this, by adding -p persistence.xml#openjpa, -p #openjpa and -connectionDriverName org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver to the command line, but it made no difference.

Comment: have you tried using a maven project?  it should make managing the dependencies easier

Comment: The requirement is very specifically not to use maven.

Comment: have you tried setting the classpath to the current directory?  also using full path?

Comment: Just tried. Added both full path instead of the / and specified each jar by its full path. Same error. Would have been surprised if there was any difference.

Comment: i looked in my project and although i use mariadb i actually use the mysql connector (5.1.33).  also i set up my datasource using TomEE so i don't define anything in the persistence.xml.  sorry i couldn't help you.  have you tried the mailing list?

Comment: Didn't, but created a bug, and that posted automatically to the mailing list, I discovered.

Comment: Just for who's curios, I downloaded the source code and ran the thing from the IDE, with similar configuration. I haven't found a place where it loads the persistence.xml file, and the configuration, when execution enters the tool, contains nothing from hibernate.xml.